# django common templates for apps with variables

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to make project-wide templates, but with app variables and app base subtemplates:

```
/home/project/
              templates/document.html
              app1/templates/app1/base.html
              app2/templates/app2/base.html
```

And app1/views.py:

```
def page1(request):
    document = get_document('title',app_email='test@example.com')
    context = {
            'document' : document,
            'app_title_header' : document.header
    }
    return render(request,'document.html', context)
```

templates/document.html

```
{% extends app_name|add:'/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
      {% autoescape off %}
      {{ document.body }}
      {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
```

(app_name is set by context_processors.py registered in settings.py)

```
def appname(request):
    return {'app_name': request.host.name, 'app_base' : '{}/base.html'.format(request.host.name) }
```

app1/templates/app1/base.html (almost identical like app2)

```
{% load static app1 %} <--- difference with app2
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
      <title>{% app_title %} - {{ app_title_header }}</title>

  {% include "app1/google.html" %}
  </head>
```

app1/templates/app1/google.html

```
{% load app1 %}
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={% g_tag %}"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', '{% g_tag %}');
</script>
```

and now:

render takes document.html from project/templates. First it extends `app_name`/base.html - so it is including google.html (Google Analytics ).

And it works. But now I want to move google.html and fb.html to project templates, but theres unique G_TAG, so it has to be a tag or sth for this. I can't just move it because of {% load app1 %} in google.html.

I think it is too complicated - and I think there's easy solution - but don't have idea which way to go.

The most important limitation - I don't want to use context_processors from apps. I use context_processor only for common things, because i use the same variables in app1 and app2 and context_processor overrides it.

Comment: Store g_tag in a model (possibly with more of those variables) and set g_tag on request via Middleware.

Comment: @Melvyn but g_tag is connected with app... Every app should have own g_tag Do you think to create the same model for every app? Very redundant

Comment: You have no shared apps? I mean, every app can just get the value from the shared app "api_tokens", or whatever. Just means that every app depends on that one app, like every app depends on Django. But they need some way to register themselves with hostname, like via Sites framework or equivalent so the middleware can set the correct value.

Comment: Or maybe I understand wrong. Do you have multiple apps in one project and want to store the rendering logic in one template and each app should provide its own value?

Comment: @Melvyn exactly one template but each app has own values

Answer (score 0):

(Note: you may be suffering from DRY fascination ~:))

You need to hardcode the value somewhere, whether it's property in a ViewMixin, retrieve it from a shared storage or a template file - thing is, you have come to the point where you the shared functionality is as insignificant as the variable that differentiates each call: you need to output the value of a variable with some surrounding elements. That variable needs to come from somewhere, so repetition of `variable = value` is going to happen in one form or another.

My 2 cents...If I didn't understand the question well enough, let me know.

So if this is in your template:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{ g_tag }}"></script>
```

And this is a view mixin:

```py
from django.views import generic
from centralapp.models import ConfigModel


class GoogleTagMixin(generic.base.ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        app_config = ConfigModel.objects.get(host=self.request.get_host())
        context['g_tag'] = app_config.google_tag
        return context
```

Then you have one template and can just use the mixin in whatever view you need it to be.

If you don't want a mixin, you can do the same with Middleware and set the value on the request object.

I'm not sure what you're looking for that is "better".

Comment: my apps are very similar but at different domains. So i want to do as much in common templates as possible. But some values are hardcoded e.g g_tag which every app has own.

Comment: So if they are in one installation but different hostnames, then use the sites framework (or similar like django-hosts) to create or use a model that has configuration for each site. In the view you can then get the value and pass it to the template as a well-known variable.

Comment: django-hosts absolutely, but it doesn't interfere with templates.

Comment: I'm not sure If I need sites, because has no problem with models (yet :D) I'd like to make templates as general as possible...

Comment: In which file/folder should this GoogleTagMixin be? And how to use it ?

Comment: Ou..https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/ Not my level yet... :(